# Get share count of a specific post Id

Tags: c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

I tried to retrieve the number of share for a specific id like this but not work return null:

```
private JsonArray SharesData(string id, string token)
    {
        JsonObject da;
        var url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/shares?access_token={1}&limit=100000", id, token);
        da = (JsonObject)fb.Get(url);
        return (JsonArray)da["data"];
    }
```

This works well against for like and comment:

```
 public JsonArray LikesData(string id, string token)
    {
        JsonObject da;
        var url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/likes?access_token={1}&limit=100000", id, token);
        da = (JsonObject)fb.Get(url);
        return (JsonArray)da["data"];
    }


 public JsonArray CommentsData(string id, string token)
    {
        JsonObject dat = new JsonObject();
        var url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/comments?access_token={1}&limit=100000", id, token);
        dat = (JsonObject)fb.Get(url);
        return (JsonArray)dat["data"];
    }
```

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no entity "share" in facebook entities (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/ for the list of entities)

However you can fetch all the stats (including number of shares) for given link using `link_stat` table.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/